# How to sort 3 columns of datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview

Below I want to sort for the columns "ProductCode", "ColorCode" and "Size". Please Guide.

Sort information in the Size column :

| Size | Number sequence |
| --- | --- |
| XS | 1 |
| S | 2 |
| M | 3 |
| L | 4 |
| XL | 5 |
| XXL | 6 |
| 2L | 7 |
| 3L | 8 |
| 4L | 9 |
| 5L | 10 |
| 6L | 11 |

```
Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim table1 As New DataTable("Players")
    table1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ProductCode", GetType(String)))
    table1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Remark", GetType(String)))
    table1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ColorCode", GetType(String)))
    table1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Size", GetType(String)))
    table1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Qty", GetType(Integer)))
    table1.Rows.Add("TEST 3000", "TEST", "BHTF10", "5L", 25)
    table1.Rows.Add("TEST 2000", "TEST", "BHTF15", "S", 55)
    table1.Rows.Add("TEST 3000", "TEST", "BHTF10", "M", 65)
    table1.Rows.Add("TEST 1000", "TEST", "BHTF25", "6L", 10)
    table1.Rows.Add("TEST 3000", "TEST", "BHTF10", "S", 12)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = table1
End Sub
```

Desired Result

| ProductCode | Remark | ColorCode | Size | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TEST 3000 | TEST | BHTF10 | S | 12 |
| TEST 3000 | TEST | BHTF10 | M | 65 |
| TEST 3000 | TEST | BHTF10 | 5L | 25 |
| TEST 2000 | TEST | BHTF15 | S | 55 |
| TEST 1000 | TEST | BHTF15 | 6L | 10 |

Comment: Bind the DataTable to a BindingSource and bind that to the grid, then set the Sort property of the BindingSource. Read the documentation to learn how but it's basically a SQL ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , Thank you for your response. `Read the documentation to learn how but it's basically a SQL ORDER BY clause.` If done without SQL can it be applied

Comment: The data is in a DataTable bound to a BindingSource. How could the Sort property even know whether the data got there via a SQL query anyway?

Comment: @jmcilhinney , `How could the Sort property even know whether the data got there via a SQL query anyway? `Actually data goes from textbox to datatable via `datatable. Rows.Add` to then passed to an empty datagridview and finally the data with an event button in via sql save to database

Comment: The point is that the data is there and that's what you're sorting. How it got there or where it goes afterwards is irrelevant. It should be obvious that it's irrelevant because, as I said, how could the Sort property know about any of that anyway?

Comment: @jmcilhinney ,  please guide me

Comment: I did guide you. I told you what property to set and to read the documentation for that property. Have you read that documentation? If not then you're not following the guidance provided.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891390/how-to-sort-a-datagridview-by-2-columns - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35214250/c-sharp-using-icomparer-to-sort-x-number-of-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So being as you've got a specific order for the size, without knowing completely how you've can derive that I'm assuming that it's stored in a table somewhere.  For simplicity's sake to facilitate the ordering you can add that to table, then hide the column in the DataGridView

I've changed the code for building the table slightly here.

```
Dim table1 As New DataTable("Players")
table1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ProductCode", GetType(String)))
table1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Remark", GetType(String)))
table1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ColorCode", GetType(String)))
table1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Size", GetType(String)))
table1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Qty", GetType(Integer)))
table1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("SizePriority", GetType(Integer)))
table1.Rows.Add("TEST 3000", "TEST", "BHTF10", "5L", 25, 10)
table1.Rows.Add("TEST 2000", "TEST", "BHTF15", "S", 55, 2)
table1.Rows.Add("TEST 3000", "TEST", "BHTF10", "M", 65, 3)
table1.Rows.Add("TEST 1000", "TEST", "BHTF25", "6L", 10, 11)
table1.Rows.Add("TEST 3000", "TEST", "BHTF10", "S", 12, 2)
```

You will notice the SizePriority column I've added and set the value to the ordering attributes for the sizes you specified at the top of your question.

Next thing to do is apply the ordering.  Using a BindingSource as was recommended by jmcilhinney in his comments would 100% be the ideal way to do this but since you seem resistant to taking his advice, I'm using a DataView (I would describe a DataView as the Visual Layer that sits over top of DataTables).    Using this you would apply the sort property using the same syntax as an Sql Order by clause.  Notice in your desired output, you had the Product code ordered descending, so added the `Desc` keyword to the sort.

```
Dim table1View As New DataView(table1)
table1View.Sort = "ProductCode Desc, ColorCode, SizePriority"
For Each row As DataRowView In table1View
    Console.WriteLine($"{row(0)}, {row(1)}, {row(2)}, {row(3)}, {row(4)}")
Next
```

Which gives me the following output

| Product Code | Remark | ColorCode | Size | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TEST 3000 | TEST | BHTF10 | S | 12 |
| TEST 3000 | TEST | BHTF10 | M | 65 |
| TEST 3000 | TEST | BHTF10 | 5L | 25 |
| TEST 2000 | TEST | BHTF15 | S | 55 |
| TEST 1000 | TEST | BHTF25 | 6L | 10 |

Answer (score 0):

To sort three columns of a `DataGridView` in VB.NET, you can use the `Sort` method of the `DataGridView` control. The `Sort` method allows you to specify the column to sort and the sort direction. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to do it:

Assuming you have a `DataGridView` named `dataGridView1` with three columns named `Column1`, `Column2`, and `Column3`, here's how you can sort them:

```vb
Private Sub SortDataGridView()
    ' Sort the first column in ascending order
    dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns("Column1"), ListSortDirection.Ascending)

    ' Sort the second column in ascending order
    dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns("Column2"), ListSortDirection.Ascending)

    ' Sort the third column in descending order
    dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns("Column3"), ListSortDirection.Descending)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the results are not yet appropriate