# How to lookup from the second source datatable to the first datatable with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, select, datatable, lookup

How to lookup from the second source datatable to the first datatable with vb.net.

Is it possible to apply lookup datatable if possible? please guide me

Thanks

```
 Private table1 As New DataTable
    Private table2 As New DataTable
    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)
        '_myTable = New DataTable
        table1.Columns.AddRange({
        New DataColumn("Column1", GetType(String)),
        New DataColumn("Column2", GetType(String)),
        New DataColumn("Column3", GetType(String)),
        New DataColumn("Size", GetType(String)),
        New DataColumn("Qty", GetType(Integer))
    })
        table1.Rows.Add("TEST 3000", "TEST", "BHTF10", "5L", 25)
        table1.Rows.Add("TEST 2000", "TEST", "BHTF15", "S", 55)
        table1.Rows.Add("TEST 3000", "TEST", "BHTF10", "M", 65)
        table1.Rows.Add("TEST 1000", "TEST", "BHTF25", "6L", 10)
        table1.Rows.Add("TEST 3000", "TEST", "BHTF10", "S", 12)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = table1
    End Sub
    Private Sub createtabletwo()

        table2.Columns.AddRange({
        New DataColumn("Size", GetType(String)),
        New DataColumn("SizePriority", GetType(Integer))
    })
        table2.Rows.Add("5L", 13)
        table2.Rows.Add("S", 2)
        table2.Rows.Add("M", 3)
        table2.Rows.Add("6L", 15)
        table2.Rows.Add("3L", 9)

    End Sub
```

Desired Result

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Size | Qty | SizePriority |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TEST 3000 | TEST | BHTF10 | 5L | 25 | 13 |
| TEST 2000 | TEST | BHTF15 | S | 55 | 2 |
| TEST 3000 | TEST | BHTF10 | M | 65 | 3 |
| TEST 1000 | TEST | BHTF25 | 6L | 10 | 15 |
| TEST 3000 | TEST | BHTF10 | S | 12 | 2 |

Comment: It looks like you want to merge the two Tables, without preserving Columns that have a match in the schema. You *could* use `[DataTable1].Merge([DataTable2], false, MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey)` (or `MissingSchemaAction.Add`), but you need a PrimaryKey with matching values in both tables

Comment: @Jimi , Thank you reply from you , `table1.Merge([table2], False, MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey) DataGridView1.DataSource = table1` I created it like this in which position I should create the primary key as you mean

Comment: For example, add a Column to each DataTable as `New DataColumn("Item_Id", GetType(Long)) With {.AutoIncrement = True, .AutoIncrementSeed = 0, .AutoIncrementStep = 1}`, then `table1.PrimaryKey = {table1.Columns("Item_Id")}` (the same for the other DataTable)

Comment: @Jimi , thank you for your reply, for manual datatable add row like this code so I have to do it because there is an error .`table1.Rows.Add("TEST 3000", "TEST", "BHTF10", "5L", 25)` `Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <TEST 3000> in Item_Id Column.  Expected type is Int64.`

Comment: You have to specify `Nothing` as the value corresponding to the PrimaryKey Column. It's an auto-incrementing Column, it auto-fills, but `.Rows.Add()` needs a *placeholder* for that position to respect the order of the Columns

Comment: @Jimi , You mean like this `table1.Rows.Add(Nothing, "TEST 3000", "TEST", "BHTF10", "5L", 25)`

Comment: If the PrimaryKey Column is the first one (occupies ordinal `0`), then yes

Comment: @Jimi , after that if I want to fill in "SizePriority" from table2 to table1 how can I do

Comment: @Jimi , `If the PrimaryKey Column is the first one (occupies ordinal 0), then yes` Yes, it is true as you said

Comment: @Jimi , means table2 that must be the primary key is  `New DataColumn("Size", GetType(String))` so `SizePriority` can appear in table1

Comment: Nope, the PrimaryKey of DataTable2 must be a Column the exact same Type and name as the PrimaryKey of DataTable1 -- You cannot reflect changes in a DataTabe in another like this. When you merge two DataTables, you copy the data, not the Columns or Rows. Columns and Rows must have a single owner, they cannot be *shared* -- You should explain in details your context: where the data is coming from, why you need to operate in two distinct tables, whether the source is a SQL query and why you're not doing this in SQL, etc.

Comment: @Jimi , I think it can be implemented from DataTable without using SQL queries.I think with datatable can be applied by assuming datatable i.e. table2 as master and datatable table1 as detail

Comment: Your example doesn't represent a master-detail relation. You have a SELECT / JOIN that requires a Foreign Key

Comment: @Jimi , sorry I misexplained so table2 it is master and table1 it is taking lookup from master table2 to populate `SizePriority`

Comment: You need to edit your question and add all the details needed to understand the context of your operations. You cannot show stuff that is unrelated to the actual data or add details / requirements as you go. Specify the source of the data and how it's acquired. The exact definitions of the Tables you're working with. whether the DGV is used for presentation ONLY or is supposed to edit the data etc. - The more precise you are, the better

Comment: I'm guessing this is a continuation of the ordering here [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76804108/how-to-sort-3-columns-of-datagridview-in-vb-net).    Why not just add an empty column to Table1 for the SizePriority, then iterate the rows and use a Select Case statement based on the Size and set the SizePriority column.  Or better yet, build it into the db query (assuming it will be a query down the track)

Comment: @Hursey , Thank you for your response. Sorry I'm late reply . `Why not just add an empty column to Table1 for the SizePriority, ` okay I added a blank column. `en iterate the rows and use a Select Case statement based on the Size and set the SizePriority column.` For this you mean using datatable select please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If looking to do using just a simple `Select Case` decision tree, nothing too complicated.  In fact I would almost go as far as to say looking over your previous questions you've posted and answers you've, you already know how to do this, you need to actually apply the logic and learnings others are giving you.

```
    Dim table1 As New DataTable("Players")
    table1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ProductCode", GetType(String)))
    table1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Remark", GetType(String)))
    table1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ColorCode", GetType(String)))
    table1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Size", GetType(String)))
    table1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Qty", GetType(Integer)))
    table1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("SizePriority", GetType(Integer)))
    table1.Rows.Add("TEST 3000", "TEST", "BHTF10", "5L", 25)
    table1.Rows.Add("TEST 2000", "TEST", "BHTF15", "S", 55)
    table1.Rows.Add("TEST 3000", "TEST", "BHTF10", "M", 65)
    table1.Rows.Add("TEST 1000", "TEST", "BHTF25", "6L", 10)
    table1.Rows.Add("TEST 3000", "TEST", "BHTF10", "S", 12)

    For Each row As DataRow In table1.Rows

        Select Case row("Size").ToString()
            Case "XS"
                row("SizePriority") = 1
            Case "S"
                row("SizePriority") = 2
            Case "M"
                row("SizePriority") = 3
            Case "L"
                row("SizePriority") = 4
            Case "XL"
                row("SizePriority") = 5
            Case "XXL"
                row("SizePriority") = 6
            Case "2L"
                row("SizePriority") = 7
            Case "3L"
                row("SizePriority") = 8
            Case "4L"
                row("SizePriority") = 9
            Case "5L"
                row("SizePriority") = 10
            Case Else
                row("SizePriority") = 11
        End Select
        row.AcceptChanges()
    Next


    Dim table1View As New DataView(table1)
    table1View.Sort = "ProductCode Desc, ColorCode, SizePriority"
    For Each row As DataRowView In table1View
        Console.WriteLine($"{row(0)}, {row(1)}, {row(2)}, {row(3)}, {row(4)}, {row(5)}")
    Next
```

Nothing any more complicated than that.  Of course, you do this using lamda/linq expressions, but this is a verbose way to do it.  Alternative since the SizePriority table is likely to be the smaller (I'm guessing) in real life, it may be better performance to switch this around.  Iterate the Size Priority table, updating Table1 using a Where clause.  I'm a bit fuzzy on the exact syntax with that now days, so going to leave it there, up to you if you want to research that.

If you're looking to do it as a query from your DB, it's just a simple join.  Nothing more complicated than that, you might even consider using the Order By clause on that query which will make this and previous question pretty much redundant.

```
Select
    <order>.Code,
    <order>.Name,
    <order>.ColorCode,
    <order>.Size,
    <order>.Quantity,
    <SizePriority>.Priority
From <Order>
    Inner Join <SizePriority> ON <SizePriority>.Size = <Order>.Size
Order By Code Desc, ColorCode, Priority
```

Note here, I don't know your DB schema so I've used `<order>` and `<SizePriority>` as placeholders, you will need to replace them with your actual table names whatever they are.  You may also need some where condition on this to filter results.

Comment: thanks answer from according to what I want. Sorry I'm late replying